# Unable to commit changes to .yml build file from the pipeline editor

Tags: azure-devops, bitbucket, azure-pipelines

When I try to save/commit changes to the .yml file from the pipeline editor I get an error saying "Error from Bitbucket: FORBIDDEN"

I have checked my permissions for the user used in the service connection in Bitbucket and the user has admin privileges. 
When I try to edit 'master' it says 'default' I have tried to modify other branches and create a new one but I get the same error.

> Unable to create a file in the Bitbucket repository 'bitbucket-
>   project/repository' for the branch 'default' and file path
>   'azure-pipelines.yml'. Error from Bitbucket: FORBIDDEN

Comment: Do you have any branch restrictions in that repo? What about IP whitelisting?

Comment: Hi, @JimRedmond I checked and here are not branche restrictions and no IP Whitelisting. 
I also tried enabling logging on the webhooks but nothing showed up.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. Will let you know if I find the answer. Meanwhile I will be commiting the code via the VCS instead of the AzDevOps GUI.